# Solr docValues usage

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am planning to try Solr's docValues to hopefully improve facet and sort performance. I have some questions around this feature:

1. If I enable docValues, will Solr create a forward index (for faceting) in addition to a separate reverse index (for searching)? Or will Solr simply create a forward index ONLY? (thus, resulting to performance gain in faceting in exchange for performance loss in searching)
2. If I want to both facet and search in a single field, what is the best practice? Should I set "indexed=true" and "docValues=true" in the same field or should I create a copy field where the source field has indexed=true while the destination field has docValues=true? (i.e. optimize the source field for search while the dest field for faceting; is this even needed?)
3. The following [documentation page](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCpyFld.html?scroll=srchCpyFld__srchFacet) from Datastax states: "*for faceting to use docValues, the schema needs to specify multiValued="true" even if the field is a single-value facet field*". I'm a bit confused - is this only true for copy fields (dest) that are to be used with docvalues or is this true even for non-copy fields?

I am using Datastax Enterprise 4.5.2

Comment: From: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues I don't think you need a copy field. The straight fwd interpretation of the doc is that setting `indexed=true` will create inverted index and `docValues=true` will create the forward index. Setting `multiValued=true` won't hurt if the field is single valued. So just try it out and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr faceting implementation will make use of DocValues only if they're marked as multivalued, so unless your field is actually multivalued, I'd suggest to use a non-stored copy field with multiValued=true and docValues=true, to avoid storing your single-value field as a Cassandra list/set.

Comment: Can I simply mark a single-valued field as multi-valued? e.g. declare a CQL string/int column as multi-valued string/int field  in Solr? Is there any harm for doing so? (e.g. performance issue) One of the fields where I want to enable docValues happen to be a CQL collection map. And since this data type is treated as dynamic field in Solr, I'm afraid I'll run into a restriction mentioned here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCqlIntro.html "Solr schema fields that are both dynamic and multivalued for CQL-backed Solr cores (only)"

Comment: Multivalued fields will be stored as lists/sets, which makes your data model a bit clumsy if they are actually single values. In your specific case, you can't do that at all as you can't have stored dynamic multivalued fields with CQL tables, but you can copy your stored dynamic field into a non-stored dynamic multi-valued field, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields.

Comment: Just to clarify: is the multi-valued attribute a requirement for faceting only or for sorting, filtering, and grouping as well? I'm a bit concerned about the additional storage requirement that I would incur in setting up a handful of copyfields just to accommodate docValues

Comment: I tried this but Solr throws an error whenever I try to use multi-valued DV fields for sorting, grouping, and stats. I have only been able to use multi-valued DV fields for faceting. So again: is the requirement for multi-valued attribute only true for faceting? i.e. for sorting/grouping/filtering/stats, DV fields can be (or must be) single-valued. If I were to use single-valued DV fields for sorting/grouping/filtering/stats, is there a way to verify that they are actually being utilized by my queries?